# Why is resized PNG image so much bigger than original image?

Tags: php, image, resize, png

I am quite confused why PNG images that are resized using GD library are much bigger in size than the original.

This is the code I am using to resize the image:

```
// create image from posted file
$src = imagecreatefrompng($file['tmp_name']);
// get original size of uploaded image
list($width,$height) = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
if($width>$maxImgWidth) {
    // resize the image to maxImgWidth, maintain the original aspect ratio
    $newwidth = $maxImgWidth;
    $newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
    $newImage=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);

    // fill transparent with white
    /*$white=imagecolorallocate($newImage, 255, 255, 255); 
    imagefill($newImage, 0, 0, $white);*/

    // the following is to keep PNG's alpha channels
    // turn off transparency blending temporarily
    imagealphablending($newImage, false);
    // Fill the image with transparent color
    $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($newImage,255,255,255,127);
    imagefill($newImage, 0, 0, $color); 
    // restore transparency blending
    imagesavealpha($newImage, true);

    // do the image resizing by copying from the original into $newImage image
    imagecopyresampled($newImage,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

    // write image to buffer and save in variable
    ob_start(); // Stdout --> buffer
    imagepng($newImage,NULL,5); // last parameter is compression 0-none 9-best (slow), see also http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php
    $newImageToSave = ob_get_contents(); // store stdout in $newImageToSave
    ob_end_clean(); // clear buffer
    // remove images from php buffer
    imagedestroy($src);
    imagedestroy($newImage);
    $resizedFlag = true;
}
```

Then I save $newImageToSave as blob in mysql database.

I tried to prevent alpha channel and just set white background, no significant change in file size. I tried setting the "compression" parameters (0 to 9), but still bigger then the original.

**Example**
I took this [image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Wikipedia-logo-en-big.png) (1058px*1296px) and resized it to 900px * 1102px. These are the results:

Original File: 328 KB
PNG (0): 3,79 MB
PNG (5): 564 KB
PNG (9): 503 KB

Any tip how to get the resized image smaller in file size is appreciated.

--

PS: I thought it could be bit depth, but as you can see, the example image above has 32 bits, whereas the resized image is 24 bits.

Comment: You're using `5` for the compression factor. Try `9` and see what happens.

Comment: I am wondering if your new dimensional size is what is causing the compression to be not as effective.  It would be interesting to see what different target dimensions would compress to what file size.  For instance if the target dimensions are one half of the original size, what is the new file size.

Comment: @MarcB Just see above: PNG (9): 503 KB

Comment: shrinking the image may very well have reduced the size of any "same color" areas, or introduced invisible banding which cuts the amount of compression possible. what happens if you simply open the original and resave it with imagepng without doing anything?

Comment: Here are a couple of references on PNG:  http://optipng.sourceforge.net/pngtech/optipng.html and http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter09.html and here is a description of the PNG technical details along with how to take advantage of them http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/15/clever-png-optimization-techniques/

Comment: @MarcB When I just load the PNG and save it again with the code above, but "resizing" to the same size, I get 463KB. Original is 328KB. PNG compresss setting is 5.

Comment: @mortezakavakebi: Click on the [image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Wikipedia-logo-en-big.png), you see it's a PNG.

Comment: Use [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) via exec

Comment: @echt: don't do ANY resizing. just `$i = imagecreatfrompng('x.png'); imagepng($i, 'out.png', 9)` and compare that.

Comment: @Baba I am on shared hosting.

Comment: @Marc B its the same .. have seen this issue before

Comment: @MarcB Using only this gives me 419 KB. `imagepng($src,NULL,5);` → compression is 5.

Comment: @Echt Einfach TV that an interesting twist

Comment: Would you prefer Jpg with white background ?? or the background of your current site

Comment: @Baba Do you mean that I should convert to JPG instead of PNG? I actually want to stick to PNG, others might face the same problem.

Comment: Never mind i found a solution see below

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't most of the functions you are calling to reduce the image , `imagefill` , `imagealphablending` etc can result to higher file size.

To Maintain the transparent use `imagecreate` instead of `imagecreatetruecolor` and just do a simple resize

```
$file['tmp_name'] = "wiki.png";
$maxImgWidth = 900;
// create image from posted file
$src = imagecreatefrompng($file['tmp_name']);
// get original size of uploaded image
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
if ($width > $maxImgWidth) {
    $newwidth = $maxImgWidth;
    $newheight = ($height / $width) * $newwidth;
    $newImage = imagecreate($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($newImage, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
    imagepng($newImage, "wiki2.png", 5); 
    imagedestroy($src);
    imagedestroy($newImage);
    $resizedFlag = true;
}
```

**Final Size : 164KB**

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Original: 328KB → Resized with your code: 163KB.  ... The only thing I don't get, why does the transparent channel survive now, with some earlier code it got black.

Comment: See my explanation ..... you are using `imagecreate` now ... its a blank slate ...

Comment: As I ran into problems regarding PNG quality (GD uses indexed 8-bit-color palette), which distorts text and colors get lost, I am using now a tip from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2650258/1066234) with this code: 

`$newImageTmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);  imagecopyresampled($newImageTmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);  $newImage = imagecreate($newwidth,$newheight); imagecopy($newImage,$newImageTmp,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight);`

The palette is determined based on the resampled result and the image quality is better (though colors get lost)!

Comment: Image with createimage directly: http://i50.tinypic.com/6egcjc.jpg   #   Image after tweak (using truecolor first, then copying): http://i45.tinypic.com/qn18gg.png

Comment: This is a different issue .. can you make it a new question

Comment: Yep, you are right. I put another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642018/optimize-png-when-resizing-with-gd-php-how-to-determine-color-palette

Comment: This answer does indeed make the file size smaller, but it is incredible BAD quality, and i mean really really bad. even if you switch out imagecreatetruecolor with imagecreate as the only change it is still very bad quality. im trying to find a solution which keeps the quality in the resized image.