# Image compression increases file size in PHP

Tags: php, image, image-compression

I have just written the PHP code to compress image size. My code compresses images but not all the time. In 10% cases, it increases the image size. Please tell why this is happening? Here is my code: (Two functions here, one for png images and other for jpg images)

```
 function compressImageSmall($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) {
    //$quality :: 0 - 100
    $info = getimagesize($source_url);

    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
    {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
        //save file
        imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);//ranges from 0 (worst quality, smaller file) to 100 (best quality, biggest file). The default is the default IJG quality value (about 75).
        //Free up memory
        imagedestroy($image);
    }
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png')
    {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);

        //imagepng($image);

        imageAlphaBlending($image, true);
        imageSaveAlpha($image, true);

        /* chang to png qulity*/ 
        $png_quality = 9 - (($quality * 9 ) / 100 );
        imagePng($image, $destination_url, $png_quality);//Compression level: from 0 (no compression) to 9.
        //Free up memory
        imagedestroy($image);

    }

    //return destination file
    return $destination_url;
}


function compressImage($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) {
    $info = getimagesize($source_url);

    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);

    //save it
    //echo '<pre>';print_r(imagejpeg($image));//
    imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);

    //return destination file url
    return $destination_url;
}
```

Comment: I have been having the same issue, with a bit of searching I found this post which looks like it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13258023/1235692

Comment: Image compression algorithms can be more or less efficient. If the image was originally created with an algorithm which was more efficient than PHP's/gd's built-in algorithm, you might see this result.

Comment: If the image is already a 'lossy' format such as 'jpeg' then it is already optimally compressed for the information it contains. Any compression you do that tries to keep the same information will, at least, add the overhead of the compression method. i.e .it will make it larger.