# Optimize PNG when resizing with GD/PHP - How to determine color palette?

Tags: php, image, resize, png

I had troubles resizing a PNG and maintaining small file sizes. [Solution found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257405/why-is-resized-png-image-so-much-bigger-than-original-image/13258023#comment18699153_13258023).

When resizing the PNG, however, I ran into problems regarding image quality. As far as I could see, GD uses indexed 8-bit-color palette which distorts text and colors get lost, see:

- [Original Image](http://i48.tinypic.com/242fwk6)
- [Resized Image with solution given above](http://i50.tinypic.com/6egcjc)
- [Resized Image](http://i45.tinypic.com/qn18gg) with a tweak²

²The idea for the tweak I found here in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2650258/1066234): Create truecolor-image, resize it, and copy it to a new image, so the palette is determined based on the resampled result and the image quality is better as you can see in the [image above](http://i45.tinypic.com/qn18gg).

```
// create new image
$newImageTmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
// we create a temporary truecolor image
// do the image resizing by copying from the original into $newImageTmp image
imagecopyresampled($newImageTmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
// create output image
$newImage = imagecreate($newwidth,$newheight);
// copy resized truecolor image onto index-color image
imagecopy($newImage,$newImageTmp,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight);
// write image to buffer and save in variable
ob_start(); // stdout --> buffer
imagepng($newImage,NULL,6);
$newImageToSave = ob_get_contents(); // store stdout in $newImageToSave
ob_end_clean(); // clear buffer
// remove images from php buffer
imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($newImageTmp);
imagedestroy($newImage);
```

Problem: None of both results are satisfactory.

I am quite sure that there must be a way to 1. determine the color palette, and 2. maintain most of the image's colors, so that 3. the PNG looks similar to the original and has an acceptable file size.

Now, I only see going for JPG instead of PNG. But if you know a solution, it would greatly be appreciated if you let me/us know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to replace

```
 $newImage = imagecreate($newwidth,$newheight);
```

With

```
 $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
```

Output `$maxImgWidth = 200;`

[image]

Comment: I tried that yesterday when facing the issue. But then the primary problem appears again: Big file size. For the example image which is originally 47 KB, I get 136 KB. So this is not a solution.

Comment: You should ask questions not say `So this is not a solution` can you save the file above ??? Its `18.5KB` without re-size its `46KB`  1KB lower than  the original  .... Since you have concluded i rather not respond again .. have a wonderful day

Comment: Sorry for my wording, English is not my mother tongue. Sorry for that. Yes, you are right, resizing the image to a width of 200px gives a small file size... I forgot to mention in the question that I resize the image to a width of `515px`. + Thanks again for the solutions you gave!

Comment: Alright, I decided to use `imagecreatetruecolor` but then use `imagejpeg($newImage,NULL,90);` instead of `imagepng($newImage,NULL,6);` which gives me (at least for the example image) similar quality and similar file size.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's fork of GD doesn't have usable palette generation, so you only get PNG32 with vanialla libpng compression.

For small PNG8 with palette use pngquant, e.g. http://pngquant.org/php.html

And then compress it further with advpng or zopfli-png.